# HTML Agility pack help getting value in table

Tags: c#, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get values from a page, the code I'm using is this :

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("url")

var nodi = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='hotellist_inner']/div"); 
string code = "";

if (nodi != null){
    foreach (var item in nodi){
       var prova = item.InnerText;   
       Console.WriteLine(code);                    
    }
}
```

It all works fine as I can get most of the informations I need except for the price.
The url is [This](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?sid=2ef5afa1e9d915b0d41cda35befba7c8;dcid=1;checkin=2014-08-28;checkout=2014-08-29;city=-132092;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;dtdisc=0;from_autocomplete=1;hyb_red=0;inac=0;nha_red=0;no_rooms=1;or_radius=0;property_room_info=1;redirected_from_city=0;redirected_from_landmark=0;redirected_from_region=0;review_score_group=empty;rows=15;score_min=0;si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi;src=index;ss_all=0;ssb=empty;sshis=0;;rows=15;offset=0).

The Xpath of the info I'm trying to access is

```
//*[@id="hotellist_inner"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/strong/b
```

But it looks like my code ignores anything in this section of the HTML.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you assign `prova` the inner text of the node, but you print out `code`?..`code` var is empty. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are right :(  I have been trying things all day and at the end gave up and posted the question without checking the code properly...sorry! I Have corrected and posted the question in a better way!

Comment: Please provide us more details about your problem. What do you mean by "except for the price"? What price? What exactly are you trying to do? Which XPath are you using out of the two you have provided?

Comment: I have written the question anew [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633380/html-agility-pack-empty-values-out-of-tables) as this one was messed up. Thanks for trying and help me out! I really appreciate!