# Html Agility Pack Empty Values out of Tables

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to learn some basic scraping and thanks to this site I have been able to learn a lot of new things, but now I am stuck with this problem...This is the code I am using:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("url");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='hotellist_inner']/div");
StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("out.txt");

if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
    {
        if (item != null && item.Attributes["data-recommended"] != null)
        {
            string line = "";
            var nome = item.SelectSingleNode(".//h3/a").InnerText;
            var rating = item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='rating']").InnerText;
            var price = item.SelectSingleNode("./div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/strong[1]");
            var discount = item.SelectSingleNode("./div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[1]");
            line = line + nome + "," + rating + "," + price + "," + discount;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            output.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

It all works fine for the first two items (name and rating), but when it comes to price and discount I get empty results. I have analized the page (here is the [link](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.it.html?sid=b77ff36c0269975901b2d41ce53a5f7f;dcid=4;ac_position=0;ac_suggestion_list_length=5;checkin_monthday=1;checkin_year_month=2014-10;checkout_monthday=2;checkout_year_month=2014-10;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;dest_id=-132092;dest_type=city;from_autocomplete=1;interval_of_time=undef;no_rooms=1;or_radius=0;property_room_info=1;review_score_group=empty;score_min=0;si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi;src=index;ss=Verona%2C%20Veneto%2C%20Italia;ss_raw=verona;ssb=empty;rows=15;)) with chrome scraper and it gets the results easily with the xpath I have used. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the web page you're trying to scrape, not all `item` has price and discount information. You need to handle this case properly to avoid exception, for example by checking for `null` before getting the `InnerText`. Your code with this slight change was able to get price and discount information where available :

```
if (item != null && item.Attributes["data-recommended"] != null)
{
    string line = "";
    var nome = item.SelectSingleNode(".//h3/a").InnerText;
    var rating = item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='rating']").InnerText;
    var price = item.SelectSingleNode("./div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/strong[1]");
    var discount = item.SelectSingleNode("./div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[1]");
    //set priceString to empty string if price is null, else set it to price.InnerText
    var priceString = price == null ? "" : price.InnerText;
    //do similar step for discountString
    var discountString = discount == null ? "" : discount.InnerText;
    line = line + nome + "," + rating + "," + priceString + "," + discountString;
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    output.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks fot the answer! I have tried your changes, but sadly I still get empty results. I can get the name and rating correctly, but the other items are empty as if there was no price at all in the source page while I can see there are some!
Why does the code work for you and not for me? :( :(

Comment: It looks as if it just won't read what's inside tables...is it possible? In fact if I try and get all HTML from the main node, I still don't get price nor discount...

Comment: My friend! I have found the reason why I cannot grab the price!! The page loaded with Web.Load is NOT the same page you would go to if you follow the link! I have made the program download the page loaded in web.load as HTML and then I opened it with a browser, and the page is different, not showing prices...why does this happen?